# how to use MediaHistory.NowPlaying Property to get current playing list in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, media-player, mediaelement

how can I get the current playing list that is playing by "music + video" app. The only thing I can get so far is the current playing song, but users will have no idea what is the next song or what list is being played.

I check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769558%28VS.92%29.aspx but it's about updating the hub. I want to update my app.....

For example, if I let's user choose to play 3rd Album in the Hub, I do it like this:

> mySongCollection = library.Albums[3].Songs;

and to update my lists I use:

> listbox.Itemssource = mySongCollection;

how can I get the current playing list from hub to mySongCollection list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way would be to loop through the [MediaPlayer.Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer.queue.aspx):

```
for(int i = 0; i < MediaPlayer.Queue.Count; i++)
{         
    Debug.WriteLine(MediaPlayer.Queue[i].Artist.Name);

    //to add the song to the listbox
    playListLb.Items.Add(MediaPlayer.Queue[i]);
}
```

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < MediaPlayer.Queue.Count; i++)
                {
                    playListLb.Items.Add(MediaPlayer.Queue[i].Name);
                  //  Debug.WriteLine(MediaPlayer.Queue[i].Name);
                }

Comment: can you explain it a little bit?

Comment: MediaPlayer.Queue[i] returns the `Song` at index `i`. Therefore, by looping through `MediaPlayer.Queue`, we can get all the Songs that are currently in the user's music list. You can see the properties of the Song class here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.song_members.aspx

Comment: I've updated the code to show the adding of items to a listbox.

Comment: where ever I place that MediaPlayer.Queue to update my Listbox, it show this error: This parameter must be a valid index within the array.
Parameter name: index .... hmm I will try to figure it out after lunch. Thanks bunch.

Comment: for some weird reason, my list show each item twice, like: song1, song2, song3, song1, song2, song3....

Comment: Did you manage to fix it? If not, could you post your code. I suspect there's something wrong in the way your `for loop` is set up.